# Default text in tcolorbox body

Tags: environments, tcolorbox, boxes

I'd like to define a tcolorbox environment, e.g.,

```
\newtcolorbox{mybox}{
enhanced,
boxrule=0pt,frame hidden,
borderline west={3pt}{0pt}{Peach},
colback=Peach!5,
sharp corners
}
```

But I would like for each box of this kind to begin with a certain keyword, e.g., "Example" – not as a title, just as a part of the body. Is there a way to build this in to the box definition?

Thanks.

Comment: Try with `before upper=Example`

Comment: @Ignasi Thanks! Do you know how I can apply a certain font/formatting to just the text in before upper? Without extending to the remainder of the body?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an alternative to my comment, it's also possible to use `attach title to upper` which includes the title in upper part. In this case, the font and color can be selected with `fonttitle` or `coltitle` options.

```
\documentclass[dvipsnames]{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}[1][]{
enhanced,
boxrule=0pt,frame hidden,
borderline west={3pt}{0pt}{Peach},
colback=Peach!5,
title=Example,
coltitle=Peach,
attach title to upper={\ },
fonttitle=\bfseries,
sharp corners,
#1
}

\begin{document}
\begin{mybox}
This is an example
\end{mybox}

\begin{mybox}[coltitle=RubineRed, title=Question]
This is a question
\end{mybox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

@Ignasi's comment already solved the main question. This answer provides how to use user defined fonts and also a tip about how to create new tcolorboxes a little more flexible.

A very basic list of fonts may be found in [this tutorial from Overleaf](https://pt.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Font_typefaces). Please notice you may have to find a package for this or that specific font, in my MWE, I used `consolas` through:

```
\usepackage{inconsolata}
\newcommand{\myfont}{\fontfamily{zi4}\selectfont\small}
```

Reading the [tcolorbox manual](https://linorg.usp.br/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.pdf) you may notice they commonly define new objects with an argument -- normally optional -- at the end of the options block. For example, in page 15, there is `\newtcolorbox{mybox}[2][]{...`, which is a two argument function, where the first argument is optional. The last line reads `...title={#2},#1}`. This `#1` is the optional argument, it is placed at the end you may add or overwrite any previously defined set.

At a first glance, this option may seem useless, *as you have already defined your style, why bothering with local options?* Well, because sometimes you may have to change something locally without creating a whole new kind of box.

OBS: *You may also define some `\tcbset` and create a new one based on a previous one, but that a skill for another answer*.

A MWE follows:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{inconsolata}
\newcommand{\myfont}{\fontfamily{zi4}\selectfont\small}

\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}
\newtcolorbox{mybox}[1][]{
  enhanced,
  boxrule=0pt, frame hidden,
  borderline west={3pt}{0pt}{blue},
  colback=blue!5,
  sharp corners,
  before upper={\textbf{\myfont{Example:} }},
  #1
}

\begin{document}
\begin{mybox}
  This is my box.
\end{mybox}
\begin{mybox}[colbacktitle=purple, title={This is mybox with option, the option is a title}]
This is my box.
\end{mybox}
\begin{mybox}[colback=red!20, borderline east={3pt}{0pt}{yellow}]
This is my box.
\end{mybox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this. It's very helpful, and I'll definitely add arg structure to my work.