# Just alter text formatting in beforeupper

Tags: fonts, formatting, tcolorbox

Trying to adjust text formatting of just the text contained in before upper, without altering the formatting for the remainder of the box.
This is my attempt now:

```
\newtcolorbox{mybox}{
enhanced,
before upper={\selectfont\bfseries\sffamily\color{defColor!80!black}{Example}},**
boxrule=0pt,frame hidden,
borderline west={3pt}{0pt}{defColor},
colback=defColor!5,
sharp corners
}
```

But this solution (for a reason I have not been able to determine) makes all the text in the box sffamily, bfseries, etc.

How do I limit the scope of these quantifiers?

Comment: Welcome! Can you please post a full (but minimal) example of code, with an instance of how you call the box?

Comment: Please, take a look at my answer to your previous question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/639527/1952 I think it solves better this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the definition in a group:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\colorlet{defColor}{green}
\newtcolorbox{mybox}{
enhanced,
before upper={\bgroup\selectfont\bfseries\sffamily\color{defColor!80!black}{Example}\egroup},
boxrule=0pt,frame hidden,
borderline west={3pt}{0pt}{defColor},
colback=defColor!5,
sharp corners
}
\begin{document}
\begin{mybox}{ grouping:}
in \LaTeX\ you can use \texttt{\textbackslash bgroup} and \texttt{\textbackslash egroup}
\end{mybox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

However, in this case it is probably better to use the variants of the font commands that take an argument, which apply the setting to the argument only. In this case `\textsf` (sans serif), `\textbf` (bold) and `\textcolor{color name}{text}` (color). These commands can be nested. In that case `\bgroup` and `\egroup` are not needed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\colorlet{defColor}{green}
\newtcolorbox{mybox}{
enhanced,
before upper={\textbf{\textsf{\textcolor{defColor!80!black}{Example}}}},
boxrule=0pt,frame hidden,
borderline west={3pt}{0pt}{defColor},
colback=defColor!5,
sharp corners
}
\begin{document}
\begin{mybox}{ font settings:}
in \LaTeX\ you can also use \verb+\textbf+, \verb+\textsf+ and \verb+\textcolor+
\end{mybox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great, clear answer. Thanks for your help.